# Visual TCL, How to install it and use it?

Tags: ruby, windows, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

im newbie with tk gui programming and i've searched for TK gui builders FOR WINDOWS platform, 
the most new program that i've found is "Visual TCL", 
but after installing it ON WINDOWS i get a folder full of tcl files...but any exe of the program...
So what i need to do now to run it???

I've readed the readme file and it says something about need to associate the tcl files with the "Wish" application...¿?
i've searched about this "wish" app on google but...nothing.

by the way, if you can recommend me a good gui builder for tk 8.5 (for Ruby, on Windows) then please...

but the question is that i want a powerfull new editor to start with this, that's the reason why i choosed by the moment "Visual TCL" (last updated on 2012), I don't want an old and desfased application for example like "guibuilder" from "active state"...or tkbuilder...

Thankyou for read.
PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows, install ActiveTcl from http://www.activestate.com/activetcl

Comment: thanks, but do you know where i can find exactly the version 8.5 x64 to download? (current is 8.5.12.0)

Answer (score 2):

You should go for vTcl_1.6.1a1 here..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vtcl/files/vtcl/1.6.1.a1/

and download the package.
Although it is in **.tar.gz** , which is a Linux understood package file, you can open it using WinZip. If you've installed WinZip, try opening this file using WinZip (it will ask you to open through its Classic View - click OK) and **Extract** its contents into your desired folder.

**vtcl.tcl** file in the root folder is the main file that you need to  run.

But before that you should have installed Tcl/Tk latest version some where from **ActiveState Tcl**. This will automatically associate all **.tcl** file extensions with **Wish Application**.

Before clicking **vtcl.tcl**, go into the folder named **lib** and open the file **tkcon.tcl** using any text editor. Replace the line (present in the very 1st **if** condition)

**package require -exact Tk $tcl_version**

to

**package require Tk $tcl_version**

save it and close it.

Now run **vtcl.tcl** and enjoy using this powerful string based scripting language.

Comment: Every time when we drag widget this gives error. "ad variable name "vTcl(w,opt,-background)": can't create a scalar variable that looks like an array element"